# how to pop-open a window on clicking a button/icon using javascript

Tags: html, css, web, chatbot

I have made a chat bot, right now i've hosted it on local server.

[image: Chat bot]

I want to embed it in my website, So what exactly I want to have is something like a button/icon hovering on right bottom side of website just like this example.

[image: button]

And on clicking it, it should pop open a chat bot window over the website. How should I proceed to do this

[image: open up window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're going to have your two things, the popup and the trigger:

```
<div class="popup">
   ... Popup Stuff
</div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

If the popup is hosted off the page you're on, you can use an iframe in the popup to render it:

```
<div class="popup">
   <iframe src="http://wherever"/>
</div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

You want the button to toggle the display state of the popup

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');

button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  popup.style.display === 'none' ? popup.style.display = 'block' : popup.style.display = 'none';
})
```